# How to send user input data from functional child component to parent class component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-bootstrap

I have a functional component which takes user input from an input field and the parent component is a class component. I want to send the user input data from functional component to class component for the validation purposes.. How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to move onChange handler to parent and pass it with props to your child component. Also you have to store your value in parent component state and pass it to child.

In this way, you child component will represent user data, but parent component will do all the stuff.

[Read more about lifting state up on **reactjs.org**](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)